Three phase motor with 3 sets of connections. Star, delta, and something else?
What's going on with this motor ? It's not simply wired into a star/delta starter. There's a 3rd option I'm not familiar with. The legend below and to the left shows Star/Star-Star/Delta.


Is it a Dahlander pole changing motor?

Might very well be. I don't have access to the actual motor.

https://i.sstatic.net/2fIFLBkM.png https://fr.scribd.com/document/188524138/European-and-American-Motor-Connections-1 https://www.wat.com.tr/baglanti-en/

https://www.electricaltechnology.org/2014/06/3-phase-motor-3-speed-1-direction-power-control-diagrams.html
